# Filtering model objects in django view

Tags: python, django, model

I'm currently creating a Social platform with Django. Right now, I'm developing their Profile page and want endusers to be able to see a timeline with their own posts. This is my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    posted = models.DateTimeField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Likes = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

In the view I wanted to filter out all the posts created by the current user. But I keep getting the error:

*invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Admin'*

This is my views:

```
@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.get(user=User.username).order_by('-posted')
    return render(request, 'Dashboard/profiel.html', {'posts':all_posts})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey @Acework! If one of the answers was a good response to your question, go ahead and accept it as the correct answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

You have three misunderstandings in your approach:

1. The `user` attribute on the Post awaits an instance of *User*. In your *filter* you compare the `user` with *User.username*, which is a CharField.
2. *User* is not the user of the current request. The user of the current request is attached on the `request` object as part of Django's Request-Response-Lifecycle.
3. You need to use `filter()` instead of `get()` when you want to get a QuerySet, instead of a single instance, see the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) on making queries.

Example:

```
@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-posted')
    return render(request, 'Dashboard/profiel.html', {'posts':all_posts})
```

Answer (score 1):

`get()` can only return 1 element in the query.

In the Django doc [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) and [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters). The part who is interesting is :

> Retrieving a single object with get()
>
> filter() will always give you a QuerySet, even if only a single object matches the query - in this case, it will be a QuerySet containing a single element.
>
> If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can use the get() method on a Manager which returns the object directly:

So use `filter` and use have a query with all matching :

```
@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-posted')
    return render(request, 'Dashboard/profiel.html', {'posts':all_posts})
```

And in your Template, your query is like a list, use loop for display it 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the current user from the `request` object:

```
@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-posted')
    return render(request, 'Dashboard/profiel.html', {'posts':all_posts})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now it gives me the error "get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!" because the current user has 2 posts, why can't he have more than 1?

Comment: replace `get()` with `filter()` like my example above.